# Oracle SQL - How do i output data from a table based on the day of the week from a hiredate column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

To be specific: I have a table with lets day 6 columns, one of which is Hiredate. the Hiredate is of the the type DATE and in the form of dd-Mon-YY. Now I am trying to only output the rows of data which have a hiredate of Monday or Tuesday.

Currently i am trying to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT name, position, hiredate
FROM table
WHERE hiredate = 'monday';
```

or

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'day') 
FROM table
WHERE TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'day') = 'monday';
```

neither of these work, and neither do any of the other variations of SQL that I have tried.

I'm fairly certain this is extremely simple, but I am a beginner and am kind of lost on where to go. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoons's answer is correct, but will only work if your Oracle session is using English language (NLS_LANGUAGE).

Another query that work for all languages is

```
select name, position, hiredate
 from table
where to_char(sysdate, 'D') in (1, 2); -- 1 monday; 2 tuesday
```

`to_char(sysdate, 'D')` returns the following values for each day of week:

```
1 monday
2 tuesday
3 wednesday
4 thrusday
5 friday
6 saturday
7 sunday
```

Comment: While I like this solution, it isn't truly NLS independent as the start of the week is dependent upon `nls_territory`. For example, Sunday is day 1 if the `nls_territory` is `AMERICA`...

Comment: @Allan That's correct. Thanks for remembering me that detail.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response. The answer was as simple as i figured it would be. I almost got this same code on my own, but i forgot to add single quotes around the 'D' and then i used in('mon','tues'). Either way it worked, and i am very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I have found Oracle's own 10g docs invaluable, you can find them here:
[Oracle 10g Doc Homepage](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage), and in this case searching for `day of week` yields some good results, like this one: [enter link description here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref427), on that page, I see:
`DAY Yes Name of day, padded with blanks to display width of the widest name of day in the date language used for this element.`

So I'm thinking that you're probably getting back Monday, but padded with spaces afterwards. I would probably try to get the abbreviated form, something like:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DY') FROM table WHERE lower(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DY')) in ('mon', 'tue');
```

Comment: This form still results in a padded answer. Either way, thanks a ton for the help and the links. i will try my best to reference the docs when troubleshooting. thanks again!